# Issue with using multiple relational operators in C

Tags: c, operators

I'm new to programming, but I searched for this topic before asking and still can't figure out what my program is doing wrong.

I have this:

```c
int i;
do
{
    i = get_int("Enter positive integer between 1-10: \n");
}
while(1>i && i<10)
```

I want to ask the user for a positive integer between one and ten. it doesn't accept anything less than one, which is good, but it will take anything positive. I understand how I can't do 1>i<10 since it reads it from left to right but I can't get it to recognize it has to follow both operators. What is my issue?

Comment: `1>i` -> `i>1`.. But you want this whole condition negated. Something like `while (i < 1 || i > 10)`

Comment: that did it, thank you. "||" means "or", right? Why would it be more applicable when the integer has to meet both criteria?

Comment: @merzy You need or so that if either the condition is satisfied(either i is less that 0 or greater than 10, you want to loop), the loop keeps running. If you are comfortable using AND, you could have used that as well using negation operator with it. Check my answer below.

Comment: merzy  Edge case question: With the prompt `"Enter positive integer between 1-10: \n"`, do you want an input of `"1"` to  loop again or exit the loop?

Comment: @merzy, The integer doesn't have to meet both criteria presented by Eugene. It has to meet *none* of the criteria to exit the loop. Meeting at least one of the criteria should keep the loop going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want the loop to run the loop as long as user inputs a number between 1 to 10. Your condition in the while loop isn't correct. It should be as follows -

```
while(i>1 && i<10); # runs as long as i is in range 1 to 10
```

However, If you want to break the loop as soon as the user inputs any number inside the `1 to 10` range, then you should use the following -

```
while(!(i>1 && i<10)); # runs as long as i is outside the range 1 to 10
```

Comment: should be `!(i>1 && i<10)`

Comment: @Ôrel Actually, first one is correct. Check my edit

Comment: for me you should ask again if the number is not into the range, while `i` is not valid you stay into the loop

Answer (score 1):

> i can't get it to recognize it has to follow both operators.
> Why would it be more applicable when the integer has to meet both criteria?

```
do {
  ....
} while(test);
```

When the test returns *true*, the input is re-tried as the loop iterates again.  *What is the criteria for re-trying*, not *what is the criteria for passing*.

Input only needs to fail **one of two** tests to re-try: too low **or** too high.  Hence the need for "or" (`||`).

```
} while(i < 1 || i > 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop condition is incorrect. You should have used **logical OR** instead of **logical AND**.

This worked for me.

```
  do
  {
    i= get_int ("Enter positive integer between 1-10: \n");

  } while (i<1 || i>10);
```

Comment: This could have been done with **logical AND**  as well. Also, you first sentence doesn't make much sense..

Comment: Makes good sense to me. You do know the difference between while and do...while I trust...

Comment: *Since you are using do...while and not while*...does that mean the condition would have been any different when using just `while()` loop? The reason to use do-while is just because i doesn't have an initial value and needs to get it from user before checking the condition

Comment: @Abhishek Gotcha, rephrased.Thanks

Comment: now its more clear. Also, do note that **logical And** could also have been used by using not operator

Answer (score 0):

you have been mistaken (`syntax mistake`) inside the while `expression` (2 mistakes their, the logic is not right and a syntnatx error with `1<i`) - see fixes inline:

```
int i = 0;  /*its better if you initialize the i here*/
do
{
    i= get_int ("Enter positive integer between 1-10: \n");
}
while((i > 1) && (i < 10));
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to ask the user for a positive integer between one and ten.

I think you want an integer in the range with inclusive 1 and 10.

When how will look such a condition of a valid positive integer?

It will look the following way

```
1 <= i && i <= 10
```

So the do while loop must continue its iterations while this condition is not true. So in the condition of the loop you should write a negation of the above condition

```
int i;

do
{
    i= get_int ("Enter positive integer between 1-10: \n");
} while ( !( 1 <= i && i <= 10 ) );
```

If to remove the parentheses then the condition will look like

```
int i;

do
{
    i= get_int ("Enter positive integer between 1-10: \n");
} while ( 1 > i || i > 10 ) );
```